# Next JS 13/14 - Server component not refetching data when revisited (Without refreshing)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

When trying to fetch the latest like items from a server component in next, thats the only data that will show until I manually refresh the page. When navigating away and returning, I want the data to be refetched but it doesn't - when using an anchor tag over Link it works

```
export default async function DjProfile({ params }) {
  const tracks = await getUserLikes(params?.id);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingGrid />}>
      <TrackContainer tracks={tracks} />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

```
const getUserLikes = async (userId) => {
  const likesRef = collection(db, "likes");
  const querys = query(likesRef, where("currentUser", "==", userId));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(querys);

  const likesData = [];

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    likesData.push(data);
  });


  console.log("new likes", likesData);

  return likesData;
};
```

Unsure how to handle this, as I am using Firestore and not next fetch which has some caching things I could add

When 'use client' is used with useEffect works fine, but for performance isnt server components better - as I don't need a live update on the actual page, just when a user navigates to it

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *When trying to fetch the latest like items from a server component in next, thats the only data that will show until I manually refresh the page. When navigating away and returning, I want the data to be refetched but it doesn't ...*

**Possible Cause:**

> Route Segment Config, by default its `auto`.

**Solution:**

Try adding this to the page :

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default function Page() {
  return <h1>Your page!</h1>
}
```

By doing this NextJs will force dynamic rendering, for each time.

**Please Read :**

1. **Route Segment Config :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
2. **Options :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#options

> ***If you still have any doubts, please leave a comment.***